# why does a = 57 b =7 r = b % a assert r == 7

Tags: python

Why does this work:

```
a = 57   
b =7   
r = b % a  
assert r == 7
```

I understand that there can be another solution "r = b / (a/a)" but I am trying to understand why the modulus method works as well.

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? 7%57 == 7 Would you have expected something else?

Comment: because this is a simple math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` returns the remainder of a division operation.

```
7 / 57 == 0  (Remember, these are integers)
```

The remainder is 7, from the above operation. Thus:

```
7 % 57 == 7
```

Comment: Thanks, i know that was terribly beginner but your explanation made sense.